# Regex to match exactly numbers of chars

Tags: java, regex

I tried to find the answer to my problem in the questions history but can't find. So here is my problem.

I have a list of string just like this:

> 1522800027011280060520140946181200900721

I solve my problem using a lot of substrings, but i think its possible to do it with a regex.
What i need to do is separate this string in few pieces, just like this:

> 152280 00270 112 8006 0520 140 946 1812 0090 0721

This string contains digits and numbers.

I am new to regex and a short explanation about how it works will help a lot.

Comment: On what basis you are separating it into numbers?

Comment: Please explain a bit more. not clear.

Comment: [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great intro to regexes. Read a bit, then if you're still having problems, post again with some details about what you've tried.

Comment: The string is just like this: 1522800027011280060520140946181200900721, the first occurrence has 6 chars, them the second one 5 chars and so on. Just like the topic.

Comment: Why don't you use `String.substring()`?

Comment: Given that this is trivial using regexes, have you done _any_ research at all? You could solve this with about 5 minutes of reading in any regex tutorial, or even just the Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

Comment: You can do this using regular expressions, but it will be less efficient than just breaking up the string at fixed positions using `substring`. Regular expressions are not the best tool for all possible string processing problems.

Comment: I think i lost some performance breaking it in some pieces. So, if not. That's ok. Ill keep doing my way. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get list from this regex:

```
r"(\d{6})(\d{5})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})"
```

I had this result as string list:

```
[('152280', '00270', '112', '8006', '0520', '140', '946', '1812', '0090', '0721')]
```

Then you can convert it to integer type.

Comment: This pattern can be seen live here: http://regex101.com/r/oH7jP7